# Expressing $2^n$ as sum of five rational cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For which positive integers $n$ can $2^n$ be written as a sum of five non-zero rational cubes ?

For which positive integers $n$ can $2^n$ be written as a sum of five positive rational cubes ?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e77vaqg4386) what Wolfram says...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $2^n$ can be written as the sum of five rational cubes, then so can $2^{n + 3}$ and $2^{n - 3}$.  The same goes for the sum of five positive rational cubes.

Allowing negative cubes, we then write
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 - 1^3 - 1^3 \\
2 &= 3^3 - 2^3 - 2^3 - 2^3 - 1^3 \\
4 &= 2^3 - 1^3 - 1^3 - 1^3 - 1^3
\end{align*}

Without negatives, it appears to be much harder: a bit of work finds
\begin{align*}
64 &= 3^3 + 3^3 + 2^3 + 1^3 + 1 ^3 \\
\end{align*}

and one experiences difficulty finding other solutions.  However, it turns out to be the case that every rational number is the sum of three positive rational cubes ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)#In_rational_numbers),
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494424/proving-that-any-rational-number-can-be-represented-as-the-sum-of-the-each-cube))
so a solution certainly exists for every power of two.  I imagine simple solutinos for, say, $32$ and $16$ could be attained with a bit of patience or programming.  This would finish the problem.