# Rational points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Consider the following elliptic curve

$y^2=(x+1540)(x-508)(x-65024)$.

It is trivial that the points $P_1(-1540,0)$, $P_2(508,0)$ and $P_3(65024,0)$ lie on this curve.
It is also quite easy to find four other integer points $P_4(-508, 262128)$, $P_5(-508, -262128)$, 
$P_6(130556, 33552384)$ and $P_7(130556, -33552384)$.

I want to find some other **rational** points on this curve. If one uses the usual group law we obtain that for every  $1\le i \le j \le 7$ we have $P_i+P_j=P_k$ for some $1\le k\le 7$. Thus we fail to obtain any new points.

Background info: I am reading a paper by Ajai Choudhry, Equal sums of seventh powers. Rocky Mountain J. Math. 30 (2000), no. 3, 849–852. The entire proof relies on finding a rational point on the curve above. Choudhry finds one such point $(x,y)$ with the denominator of $x$ being $12$ digits long. He does not explain how he achieved this discovery. Are there any other simpler rational points? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It can't be that paper. There's no proof yet that $x_1^7+x_2^7+\dots+x_8^7 = 0$ has an infinite number of primitive solutions.

Comment: You are right Tito, I mentioned the wrong article. The relevant paper is On Sums of Seventh Powers, Journal of Number Theory 81(2000), 266-269. My initial question was how did the author found the values of a, b, c, d at the bottom of page 267? I became familiar to Choudhry's work only very recently; I like his results quite a bit, but his style is usually very terse, and he skips a lot of details. Hope this clarifies things. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I have read some of Choudhry's papers on equal sums of powers, which are all very interesting, but the terseness is certainly recognizable. In the mentioned paper how do the values of $a,b,c$ and $d$ relate to the elliptic curve above? If there is such a connection, can you clarify it?

Comment: @DanIsmailescu: I realized that given your elliptic curve, $$(x + 1540)(x - 508)(x - 65024)=y^2$$ the transformation $x =4u+65024,\;y=8v$ transforms it to, $$u(u + 127^2)(u +129^2)=v^2$$ which is Rusin's version mentioned below. I should have seen it earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a background to the question, Choudhry [showed](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X99924654) that the eqn,

$$x_1^7 + x_2^7 + \dots + x_n^7 = 0$$

has an infinite number of primitive integer solutions for $n=9$. He used the *polynomial identity*,

$$(x + a)^7 + (x - a)^7 + (m x + b)^7 + (m x - b)^7 + (-x - c)^7 + (-x + c)^7 +\\ (-m x - d)^7 + (-m x + d)^7 + (-14(a^6 + m b^6 - c^6 - m d^6)N)^7 = 0\tag1$$

where,

$$x =14^6(a^6 + m b^6 - c^6 - m d^6)^6N^7$$

for arbitrary $N$ though one must solve the simultaneous equations,

$$\begin{aligned}
a^2+m^5b^2 &= c^2+m^5d^2\\
a^4+m^3b^4 &= c^4+m^3d^4
\end{aligned}\tag2$$

In appropriate cases, this can be reduced to an *elliptic curve*. For $m=2$, Choudhry found the *smallest* integer solutions $a,b,c,d$ as the **33**-digit numbers,

$$292565171139318137956759657471297,\\ 863420822620431936290192229011966,\\ 
534407060429869176086407612538177,\\ 859793943610761912321826231621886$$

implying the coefficients of $(1)$ are as high as $x \approx (28d^6)^6 \approx 10^{1180}$.

Dave Rusin [reduced](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6895431) the system $(2)$ to an elliptic curve. Let $q=(1-m^7)/(1+m^7)$, then,

$$U(U+1)(U+q^2)=V^2\tag3$$

With $(2)$ being the case $m=2$, so $q=-127/129$. For simplicity, let $U=u/129^2,\;V=v/129^3$ and we get,

$$u(u+127^2)(u+129^2)=v^2\tag4$$

The symmetry of $(4)$ allows that for non-zero $u_k$, then,

$$u_{k+1}=\frac{(127\cdot129)^2}{u_k}\tag5$$

is also a solution. Excluding the torsion points, there are *eight* "small" solutions (with $u_5$ courtesy of Jeremy Rouse in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191605/)),

$$u_1 =\small \Bigl(\frac{\color{blue}{77684960}\sqrt{129}}{79\cdot12497}\Bigr)^2=-129^2+\Bigl(\frac{\color{blue}{78490049}\sqrt{129}}{79\cdot12497}\Bigr)^2$$

$$u_3 =\small -\Bigl(\frac{891195649\sqrt{129}}{78490049}\Bigr)^2=-129^2+\Bigl(\frac{15796208\sqrt{258}}{78490049}\Bigr)^2$$

$$u_5 =\small \Bigl(\frac{\color{green}{224312161}\sqrt{127}}{1079\cdot24423}\Bigr)^2=-127^2+\Bigl(\frac{\color{green}{372170768}\sqrt{127}}{1079\cdot24423}\Bigr)^2$$

$$u_7 =\small -\Bigl(\frac{264770431\sqrt{127}}{23260673}\Bigr)^2=-127^2-\Bigl(\frac{26352417\sqrt{254}}{23260673}\Bigr)^2$$

and *distinct* $u_2,\,u_4\,u_6,\,u_8$ derived by using $(5)$. Note that,

$$\color{blue}{77684960}+\color{blue}{78490049} = 12497^2$$

$$\color{green}{224312161}+\color{green}{372170768} = 24423^2$$

**P.S.** The first four $u_i$, after removing common factors, yield the same $a,b,c,d$ as above. Why are the $u_i$ seem so "structured"?

---

**Edit:** (Jan 2018) There are other "smallish" solutions,

$$u_9 = \small\Bigl(\frac{3399461793\sqrt{127}}{224312161}\Bigr)^2=-127^2+\Bigl(\frac{4236326896\sqrt{127}}{224312161}\Bigr)^2=-129^2+\Bigl(\frac{48010029072}{224312161}\Bigr)^2$$

$$u_{10} = \small\Bigl(\frac{125382401\sqrt{129}}{77684960}\Bigr)^2=-129^2+\Bigl(\frac{891195649\sqrt{129}}{77684960}\Bigr)^2=-127^2+\Bigl(\frac{9968236223}{77684960}\Bigr)^2$$

Comment: @JesperPetersen: In the link that I cited, Rusin mentions that the elliptic curve $$u\bigl(u+(n^7-1)^2\bigr)\bigl(u+(n^7+1)^2\bigr)=v^2$$ other than $n=2$, also has rational points for $n=5,6$. That was 5 years ago. Is it now feasible for Sage to search for those points, or not yet?

Comment: For the case $n=2$ the generator of the free part is returned almost instantly, which is not the case for $n = 5,6$. As would be expected. How long it would take to find the generator I don't know how to estimate. I am wondering what sparks the interest in the more general case. Obviously, a point for $n > 2$ would unearth solutions to the sum-of-seventh-powers equation not mentioned in Choudhry's paper, but are there any other implications?

Comment: @JesperPetersen: Other than knowing that it is doable? I guess it is the same curiosity why I wanted to see a third elliptic curve for $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$ in this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191316/). But thanks for the try. :)

Comment: Doesn't the claim that $x_1^7+\cdots+ x_9^7=0$ has infinite many integral primitive solutions not contradict Falting's theorem ?

Comment: @Peter: It is not just a claim, but Choudhry _showed_ that $x_1^7 + \dots + x_9^7 = 0$ has infinitely many primitive integer solutions, that is, the $x_i$ have $\gcd(x_i) = 1$. (The actual polynomial identity is given above.) I do not see how [Faltings's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings's_theorem) is applicable to this particular Diophantine equation. There are even $8$th deg and $10$ deg similar versions of this.

Comment: @JesperPetersen: MacLeod found the case $n=5$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594688/an-elliptic-curve-xx-781262x-4-times57-y2-for-x-17x-27-dots).

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I had a typo in my first post. The conclusion is now different.

As suggested by Amzoti, you can use Sage freely at cloud.sagemath.com. With your curve you'll find out this:

sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,-63992,0,-67887088,50869575680])

sage: E.torsion_points()

[(-1540 : 0 : 1),
 (-508 : -262128 : 1),
 (-508 : 262128 : 1),
 (0 : 1 : 0),
 (508 : 0 : 1),
 (65024 : 0 : 1),
 (130556 : -33552384 : 1),
 (130556 : 33552384 : 1)]

sage: E.gens()

[(100132172429824908929/1508738252550400 : 143687064081412107244001809983/58603135399923860992000 : 1)]

So the points you have found is all of the torsion group, which is why applying the group law on these points will give you no further points. The rank is $1$ and so you can find further points by computing multiples of the generator of large height that Sage found.

Comment: Thank you Jesper, this is so cool! I will definitely give Sage a try.

Comment: If $P_i$ denotes the point on $E$ with $x$-coordinate $x_i$, then $P_2 = P_1 + T$ where $T$ is the torsion point with $x$-coordinate $508$. The curve $E$ and $V^2=U(U+1)(U+q^2)$, $q=\frac{-127}{129}$ are isomorphic -- they have the same minimal model according to Sage. I am not sure that I understand the significance of the numbers that repeat, but I guess that it has to do with the isomorphism between the curves.

Comment: @JesperPetersen: I used your answer to find another "small" point in Rusin's elliptic curve. They have interesting relationships, it seems.

Comment: I was not aware of Rusin's derivations. Here are my own computations. Hope this helps. Please check the link below.                 https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytc1hlcrl7mmjco/derivation_elliptic_curve_seven_powers.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @DanIsmailescu: Thanks, Dan. By the way, I edited my answer to include both solutions of form $127p^2, 129q^2$ for balance. This [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191605/) related to your elliptic curve might be of interest.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: That's very interesting Tito. Do you know of any other instances where the problem can be reduced to an elliptic curve?

Comment: @DanIsmailescu: There's a lot. In *equal sums of like powers*, many Diophantine problems need $$ax^2+by^2 = z^2,\quad cx^2+dy^2=t^2$$ to be solved simultaneously, leading to an elliptic curve. See my website, especially for [eight powers](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/028). The cases $p^4+q^4+r^4 = s^4$ and $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = e^4$ also need elliptic curves. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509526/) and [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191316/).